# References for Euclidean geometry of quadrilateral

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, book-recommendation, online-resources, quadrilateral

I'm quite familiar with the results in Euclidean geometry of triangles. However, it's not the case with quadrilateral.

Is there any sources to learn and to check the complicated, advanced results in the geometry of quadrilateral?

Comment: What are you interested in? The interior angles add up to a full circle? A quadrilateral is cyclic if opposite angles add up to a half circle? Apart from squares and parallelograms, Euclid dealt with general quadrilaterals far less than triangles

Comment: I'm interested in much more advanced results, like Miquel theorem, etc...

Comment: Mastering triangles is one way to learn about quadrilaterals (and polygons in general). There are many instances where dissecting a polygon into triangles is more than enough to prove a theorem about polygons. To address your problem more directly, "much more advanced results" about quadrilaterals can be found in any decent olympiad geometry book, provided that you are familiar with concepts like spiral similarity, which are useful when discussing quadrilaterals.

Comment: @dodoturkoz Yes, you're right, however, for some people like me, when we want to check some results we discover along the way learning mathematics, a good source is the light. For example, recently I found out this https://imgur.com/WURDwQ0 and I really want to know if it's a well-known theorem in quadrilateral geometry or not. That's why the question here.

Comment: I found this link incidentally: https://www.chrisvantienhoven.nl/quadrilateral-objects hope it would help others and me as well.